# EJB method not found

Tags: java, ant, jboss, ejb, liferay-6

I am using liferay 6.1 and working on Eclipse IDE.

An EJB project which i copied from another PC (which uses JDK 1.7 same as mine).
I am compiling this EJB project and exporting it as a jar and using it on my liferay portlet.

so basically i call the ejb method. surprisingly, i can call all the methods which was already there. but now when i add new method on my remote interface like this:-

```
@Remote
public interface PreExaminationRemote {
  public String dummy();
}
```

**Implementation class**

```
@Stateless
public class PreExamination implements 
PreExaminationRemote,PreExaminationLocal{
  public String dummy(){
  return "works";
 }
}
```

and call it from controller of my portlet it will simply throw an exception of method not found.

```
Exception in thread "liferay/scheduler_dispatch-1" 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
com.test.PreExaminationRemote.dummy()Ljava/lang/String;
```

I am using ant to build the jar file. 
1. I tried ant clean.
2. I tried to clean the ejb project
3. I changed the workspace

nothing seems to work.

Comment: What does your EJB look like? Does it implement that method? And did you make sure Liferay gets the new version of your jar?

Comment: yes it does. it simply returns a string value.

Comment: Don't you need to annotate the method with `@EjbMethod`?

Comment: i export this ejb project as jar (Preexamination.jar) and put it inside WEB-INF/lib folder. it always worked before but not sure why this is not working this time.no i don't need to annotate as i am using JNDI lookup.

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect, without fail, that this exception shows up when you have outdated code around. This might be the application server's cache, duplicate code (e.g. two different jars on the same classpath, with the same code in different versions) or locked files that couldn't be overwritten.

Search through the available classpath, don't forget appserver-globals, your own WEB-INF/lib and the appserver's temp and work directory before redeployment. To work around locked files (e.g. under Windows), reboot, redeploy and check if it still fails to work.

I don't see any other explanations for this behavior.